# Send Signature in Mail JAVA

Tags: java, gwt

I am sending a mail in GWT using Google Oauth Authentication and token.
My Project use Google OAuthAuthentication.
The mail is send successfully . I just want to automatically include signature like we do in our mails while sending the mail.

I am able to send mail :

```
SMTPTransport transport = connectToSmtp(from, token);
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(toMail));
msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccMail));
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
msg.setSubject("Imprest Report");
msg.setContent(messageBody ,"text/html; charset=utf-8");
transport.sendMessage(msg,msg.getAllRecipients());
```

Comment: The code i use is shown in question..

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add the signature as part of the "content" since I don't think email APIs supports signature as a concept

Comment: Signature is send automatically when we send mail...but here it is not.   I don't want to hard code it. I want if other user want to send mail,it should automatically use that person's signature.

Comment: Understood, but the problem is there is no default support for signatures. You don't have to hard code, handle that in the application layer where for you provide your app users ability to save their signatures, you could persist that to DB table, do a DB look up and append as part of content. Hope that helps